# Как вывести отличающиеся ключи в двух JSON?

Tags: python-3.x, json, dict, parse

Я бы хотел подтягивать два JSON файла (они почти идентичны) и чтобы ключи, которые не сходятся выводились на экран (это для быстрой правки разных ключей). Нашел вот такое решение:

```py
import json

with open('file name.json') as a:
    text = json.load(a)

with open('file name 2.json') as b:
    text2 = json.load(b)

if text == text2:
    print(True)
else:
    c = set(text.keys()) ^ set(text2.keys())
    print(c)
```

(выводит разность ключей)
Но выводит мне вот это:

> set()
> Process finished with exit code 0

Никогда не работал с JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте разберем, что у вас происходит.
Вот здесь вы сравниваете словари полностью

```py
if text == text2:
    print(True)
```

т. е. и ключи и значения и если на вход подать два вот таких словаря (ключи одниковы, значения нет)

```py
text = {'test': 1, 'test2': 2}
text2 = {'test': 1, 'test2': 3}
```

тело `if`а не отработает и пойдет дальше в `else`.

В этой части кода:

```py
else:
    c = set(text.keys()) ^ set(text2.keys())
    print(c)
```

вы работаете только с ключами и при тех же входных данных (словари `text` `text2`), переменная `c` будет содержать пустой `set()`, что в принципе у вас и получается.

Если вы ищите разность только ключей, то и работайте только с ключами в условии

```py
if text.keys() == text2.keys():
    print(True)
else:
    c = set(text.keys()) ^ set(text2.keys())
    print(c)
```

при таком условии вывод будет `True`.

Если же вы ищите отличие **значений** под одинаковыми ключами, то

```py
  c = set(text.keys()) ^ set(text2.keys())
```

не подходит

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли разобраться)
а почему, если я меняю часть кода на 
if text.value() == text2.value():
    print(True)
else:
    c = set(text.value()) ^ set(text2.value())
    print(c)
то выдает
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'

значения словарей вроде же называются - value?
то есть не достаточно поменять с text.keys() на text.value() ?

Comment: а, извините) я загуглил - values, а не value
все, вопросов больше нет, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Dmitry для обращения к ключам и значениям за один проход существует метод `items()`. `for key, values in text.items():` - удобная конструкция для работы со обеими сущностями за раз

Comment: Спасибо! А я чуть по другому сделал) но этот метод лаконичней